# ListView performance with complex views as list items

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I had ran into problem with performance. I have to develop *complex* ui based on ListView and really complex item layout contained nested layouts, custom views, lot of images etc.
The problem is as usual, when client is creative and has no limit credit card: performance.
Creating of list view lasts ~10 seconds on fast device.
When I profiled application, I discovered, that most of the CPU power is used for onMeasure method - you know how it works - measuring of the width, passing measure demand to children, getting them into lauouts, asking layouts to change it's height, then measure once again with new bounds - horror.
I can't show you the screen with the layout - just say that there is ~80 views in each item - no we can't do less.
My idea is based on simple observation - every single one sub view on particular device has this same size - i.e. if I have an image view to display inside the list item - on each item it will have **exactly this same size**.

So I want to make some cache for dimensions - i.e. - I have LinearLayout containing bunch of views, I want to perform simple algorithm:
Create CustomLayuout extending LineraLayout
put members like width, height (i.e. static)
when view is created for a first time I want to get it's size put it into static vars and reuse them when next instance of the view will be created.

After this (a bit long) description finally my questions:

1. Can I apply approach like that, or there are some serious
   disadvantages?
2. How to do it (code sniplets welcomed)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am skeptical that this will help performance. Presumably, a lot of those ~80 views are containers (`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc.), where you are encoding your positioning rules. If so, I suspect that you will get better results out of creating a custom `ViewGroup` that handles all of those positioning rules on its own, so you can cut back the number of total views per row. Look for other ways of consolidating views (e.g., compound drawables with `TextView` rather than using a `LinearLayout` and `ImageView`).

Comment: Sure do it if I can, but do not seeing possibility for that - there is also some navigation (show/hide some overlays). I have zero influence for UI of this project and just can't make slight adjustments to make it work other way.